# Spring 4 Annotation-based controller not working in Jboss 5.2

Tags: controller, annotations, spring-4

I have tried to create a very simple controller with Spring 4.0.2. It works fine if I used version 3.1.2.RELEASE. However, once I upgraded the maven dependency to 4.0.2.RELEASE. It stop working.

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>my-app</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my springDispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"  
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tsun.sample"/>
<bean  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" 
/>
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" 
/>
</beans>
```

Here is my controller

```
package com.tsun.sample;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test.json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String simpleMethod(ModelMap model) {
        return "hello";
   }
}
```

Here is my hello.jsp in WEB-INF/jsp

```
HELLO WORLD!
```

When I try

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/test.json
```

There is error
2014-03-14 14:38:34,417 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-app/test.json] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'

Did I miss anything? It works fine for Spring version 3.1.2
Any feedback is welcome!

Thank you

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you first try migrating to Spring 3.2?
Using the [official migration guide to 3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#migration-3.2) should help you. Also in your case, I think the annotation beans could be replaced by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- your other beans -->

</beans>
```

Once done, you can then rely on the [guide to Spring 4 migration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework).

Don't worry, both guides are really lightweight, and separating both tasks should help a lot. Note: check out the [Spring 4 dependency update](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#dependency-updates) for minimal requirements. It looks like some of the requirements aren't met by Jboss 5.2. Things may work, but won't have access to official support.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is to do with the component scanning not correctly finding resources due to Spring 4 removing the support for the version of the Virtual File System (VFS) used by JBoss 5.2.

Antoine Rey has [discussed this](http://javaetmoi.com/2014/04/support-vfs2-jboss5-spring4/) (in French) and has developed a fix which is [available from Github](https://github.com/arey/spring4-vfs2-support/).